# Why won't Safari OSX play YouTube videos?

Tags: safari, video, youtube

When I display a video, I see this message: [image]

When I click through to the message about HTML support I see:
[image]

Yet we know that Safari supports H.264.

Other notes - YouTube videos play in Chrome without trouble. Vimeo videos play in Safari no problem. This problem isn't version specific I've had it for eons. Disabling all extensions doesn't help.

OS version High Sierra 10.13.2
MacBook Pro - Early 2015
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB

Comment: Strange. I have an old iMac running High Sierra. I just went to YouTube and videos played fine.  My computer is mid-2010 so I'd expect your graphics to be far better than mine.